# Enlarge small caps and memoir headers

Tags: macros, header-footer, memoir, small-caps

I enlarged the small caps of my font by using the `letltxmacro` package. This works fine in text, chapter titles, etc., but I'm using the `\pagestyle{ruled}` under `memoir` which causes even page headers to contain the chapter title in small caps. When using the `LetLtxMacro` however, these headers disappear (well, the ruler stays but the text disappears). Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgpagella}
\usepackage{letltxmacro,lipsum,relsize}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldscshape}{\scshape}
\renewcommand{\scshape}[1]{\oldscshape\relscale{1.2}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\chapter{Title with \textsc{small caps}}
\section{Section title}
some text \textsc{some text} some text
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `\renewcommand{\scshape}[1]{\oldscshape\relscale{1.2}#1}` although I am not sure if this is the most convenient way to increase the size for your small caps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than doing nasty tricks with `relsize`, I'd scale the fonts directly:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{tgpagella}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{sc}{<-> [1.14] ec-qplb-sc}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{b}{scit}{<-> [1.14] ec-qplbi-sc}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{sc}{<-> [1.14] ec-qplr-sc}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{T1}{qpl}{m}{scit}{<-> [1.14] ec-qplri-sc}{}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\chapter{Title with \textsc{small caps}}
\section{Section title}
some text \textsc{some text} some text
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I use that 0.95*1.2=1.14; the lines have been taken from `t1qpl.fd`.

[image]